# Moodle best way to get information about user points in course and the whole points in the course

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am seeking assistance in determining a user's overall score and the maximum achievable score in a course. My goal is to calculate the percentage of total points the user has achieved throughout the entire course. Additionally, I am interested in the ability to set and retrieve a predefined threshold, representing a specific percentage of points, through an API.

I initially attempted to use the `core_completion_get_course_completion_status` function. However, I encountered an error for some courses, indicating that completion criteria were not set. Subsequently, I considered downloading all activities in the course and retrieving user results from each. However, the volume of data obtained led me to reconsider this approach as it seems overly complex.

I am in search of a simpler method to achieve these goals. If you have any suggestions or insights, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: Go to Site Admin > Server > Web Service > API Documentation then search the page for "grad" [no "e"] then you will find a few grade/grading API functions. Maybe `gradereport_overview_get_course_grades` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using method `gradereport_user_get_grade_items`.
From the response provided I managed to get a list of objects and iterate over it until I find an item with property: `itemtype` set to `course` and `gradeisoverridden` set to `false`. From this item I can get:

- `graderaw` - raw value of the grade
- `gradeformatted` - string representing formatted grade
- `grademin` - minimal grade that can be obtained
- `grademax` - maximum grade that can be obtained

To the request I must add such headers:

- `wstoken` - access token (with needed permissions)
- `wsfunction` - moodle method (`gradereport_user_get_grade_items`)
- `moodlewsrestformat` - optional (json, xml - default)
- `courseid` - ID of the course
- `userid` - ID of the user for whom the grade is being searched

Curl example:

```
curl --location '<YOUR_URL>/webservice/rest/server.php' \
--form 'wstoken="<YOUR_TOKEN>"' \
--form 'wsfunction="gradereport_user_get_grade_items"' \
--form 'moodlewsrestformat="json"' \
--form 'courseid="<YOUR_COURSE_ID>"' \
--form 'userid="<YOUR_USER_ID>"'
```